How to use stockfish with c++?
I downloaded the stockfish.exe from the website and it runs fine. I just want to give it a position and to return an eval. The documentation about c++ in the stockfish website is gone. What can I do?
I know how to communicate with the executable using the UCI protocol, but I don't know how to do it in code.

For those wondering if such questions are off topic could I direct you to the help center (https://chess.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) where more information is available. In particular "Chess-specific questions about programming a chess engine or other chess software are welcome".

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832326/how-can-i-execute-a-command-line-command-from-a-c-program
10 seconds search returned this since engines are command line tools, or that is what i think.
is it what are you looking for?
but somehow i believe python has a better way to communicate with engines you should look it up.
